# Upgrade to new version of JasperServer

Tags: ireport, jasperserver

How in the world do I go about updating to the new version  of JasperServer? Their site has no real documentation on how to accomplish this.

I have downloaded the JasperServer archive (Windows, btw), but what is next?

---

The reason for doing this is that the new version of iReport has some sort of file compatibly issue with it's own new jrxml file, and the current fix is updating JasperServer.

Comment: Well my boss got me into this mess, he installed whatever I needed to use iReport. So I think actually what we need to do is replace JasperServer with the new version. I'm having compatibility issues with my new jrxml files out of iReport 4.0.2. So I will correct my question. Thank you for helping me clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read the [JasperServer install guide](http://www.google.com/search?q=jasperserver+install+guide).
2. Read about the `js-export` and `js-import` commands.

In the past, I did the following:

1. Use `js-export` to save a copy of the reports.
2. Install a new database.
3. Install the latest JasperServer version.
4. Use `js-import` to load the previously exported reports.

Answer (score 2):

The reason they don't say how to do it is because JasperReports isn't a standalone app that end users upgrade themselves - it's a library used for reporting features. If you didn't build the application that uses JasperReports yourself you don't really have any reason to upgrade to 4.0.2.

If you did build the application yourself, then you just need to swap the jars from the old jasperreports out with the new ones and then test to make sure there weren't any breaking changes made to the API. (The changelog doesn't seem to indicate there were any, but you don't ever indicate what version you are upgrading from so perhaps there are some)

If you are using something like maven to build whatever you are using, you can update the version in the dependency information and run a new build and after all your existing unit tests pass you can run your app with the new version of jasperreports and make sure it is all still working.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I was meaning JasperServer not JasperReports.